# Преобразовать массив на шарпе в json

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть код на php:

`$postData = array(
            'filter' => array('email' => array('type' => 'primary', 'email' => $state)), 
        );`

Могу я сделать такой же json массив на шарпе? Я пробовал вот так:

```
var x = new
        {
            filter = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            email = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    type = "primary"
                },
                new
                {
                    email = email
                }
            }
        }

    }
        };
```

Но пишет нет подходящего типа для неявно типизированного массива.

Comment: `new object[] `

Comment: вы что то спрашиваете про json, но у вас нет json в вопросе.

Comment: Создает такую строку 
{"filter":[{"email":[{"type":"primary"},{"email":"sales@team.eu"}]}]}

Это правильный json массив? Ибо пока api не хочет на него реагировать, не знаю в нем причина или нет.

Comment: В апи указан такой массив:
\"filter\": {
    \"email\": {
      \"type\": \"primary\",
      \"email\": \"info@piedpiper.eu\"
    },

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Не пишите важную информацию в комментариях. Пишите всё необходимое в самом вопросе (отредактируйте его).

Comment: В json объекты заключаются в фигурные скобки, массивы в квадратные. В коде C# вы создаёте массивы. Неудивительно, что в json получаете квадратные скобки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Создавать массивы не следовало. Создал Dictionary и все заработало. Вот код:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> dict =
            new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

        Dictionary<string, string> email = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        email.Add("type", "primary");
        email.Add("email", (string)emailUser);

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> keys = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        keys.Add("email", email);

        dict.Add("filter", keys);




        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```